# How do I shut down without the confirmation prompt?

Tags: shutdown

> Are you sure you want to close all
>   programs and shut down the computer?

When I click shut down I want to shut down! :) This message bugs me. How to avoid this message?

Comment: I am looking for an answer for 12.04

Comment: Verified answer for 11.10 works for 12.04, edited answer to include 12.04 in title.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### For 12.04 an later

Settings for the indicator session and logout menu are found by running **dconf-editor** (from [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools])

[image]

Comment: I can't find this key in Kubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 26):

**11.04 and previous versions of ubuntu**

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and enter this: `gconf-editor`
- apps > indicator-session
- select `suppress_logout_restart_shutdown`

[image]

OR

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and enter this:

**`gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/indicator-session/suppress_logout_restart_shutdown true`**

To re-enable confirmation, replace the keyword `true` with `false`

Answer (score 2):

- press `Alt+F2` and type `gconf-editor`
- go to `/apps/indicator-session` and check items you want

Answer (score 2):

#### For 10.04

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>, wait 60s or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

No mouse involved - but fastest way I know of.

#### For 11.10 and later

The above keys shortcut lead to the logout dialog only. To assign a keyboard shortcut to the power off dialog we open

```
gnome-control-center keyboard
```

or *Keyboard* from *System Settings...* to define a new *Custom Shortcut* for the command

```
gnome-session-quit --power-off
```

This will open the following shutdown window:

[image]

In case we want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> for this we may have to define another shortcut for *System -> Log out* first.

Comment: There's an option not to prompt the user: `gnome-session-quit --power-off --force --no-prompt`

Answer (score 2):

If you have Ubuntu Tweak installed you can do this by selecting Session control from the left hand side list and tick the box *Suppress the logout, restart and shutdown confirmation dialogue box*.

Check this question for Ubuntu tweak installation

- [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)

Comment: For me personally in 11.10 I tried half a dozen different posted fixes checking and un-checking things various config editors and Ubuntu-Tweak was the only thing that actually worked. In the current version it is under Tweaks > Session Control

Answer (score 1):

#### For GNOME2 panel (10.04 LTS)

Add Logout Button to GNOME Panel.

[image]

This is **1** mouse click to start the 60s shutdown countdown (immediate shutdown involves another mouse clicks).

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal and type `sudo chmod u+s /sbin/shutdown`

Then, from that point forward, any user can just issue the command `shutdown` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

#### For Ubuntu 12.04 (Tested on 12.04, should also work on other versions)

Just open a terminal and run this command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-logout-restart-shutdown true
```

That's it. To re-enable just change the `true` to `false`.

The good thing about this is, You don't need to install dconf-tools, though it is better to install it, which will give you a graphical settings editor called dconf-editor to change many other features

Answer (score -1):

Easy Pease.

Right click application menus.

Edit Menu.

GOTO - System Tools.

Click on "tick box" for the configuration editor.

Bingo.

Exit.

Applications, System Tools. configuration editor. // Apps - Indicator Session. Click the tick boxes to see exactly what they do and then untick them... and use this one.

/apps/indicator-session/suppress_logout_restart_shutdown

Suppress the dialog to confirm logout, restart and shutdown action.  Whether or not to show confirmation dialogs for logout, restart and shutdown actions.