# How do I remove the shutdown confirmation menu?

Tags: menu, shutdown, notification

How do I remove the shutdown confirmation menu saying "are you sure you want to shut down"?   This is the menu that pops up after I press shut down.

I can't navigate to it in gconf_editor using the old instructions for 10.04 or 11.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power button instant shutdown](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66723/power-button-instant-shutdown)

Comment: Do you mean the choice screen (that lets you click shutdown, restart, log out, etc) or the window that pops up when you click shutdown (from various screens) that gives you the option to shutdown or cancel? I've not explained that particularly well!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I shut down without the confirmation prompt?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14794/how-do-i-shut-down-without-the-confirmation-prompt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## For 11.10

Run `dconf-editor`
(either Alt+F2 or from terminal, must be installed first)

```
/org/gnome/gnome-session/
```

uncheck "logout-prompt"

I still haven't found a way to return restart to the menu  and suppress that confirmation.
(thanks for the edit fossfreedom)

Comment: Mine is unchecked, but it still prompts me, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

## For 10.04/10.10 & 11.04

Run `gconf-editor`
(either Alt+F2 or from terminal)

```
/apps/gnome-session/options
```

uncheck "logout_prompt"

```
/apps/indicator-session
```

check "suppress_logout_restart_shutdown"

This will remove the annoying dialog in releases preceding Oneiric Ocelot.

Answer (score 1):

### Ubuntu 13.10

Open a terminal and run `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-logout-restart-shutdown true`. This will disable the dialog.

by *Donarsson*: [shut down without extra question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425813/shut-down-without-extra-question/425814?iemail=1&noredirect=1#425814)

Answer (score 0):

For me in Ubuntu 11.10:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor dconf-tools
dconf-editor
```

Go to `/apps/indicator-session`

Enable: *suppress-logout-restart-shutdown*

Cheers!