# shut down without extra question

Tags: unity, shutdown

When I select shutdown in the top right corner, I get an extra question in a new window in the middle of the screen with a big button to shut down.

How can I directly shut down Ubuntu 13.10, without extra question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a terminal and run `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-logout-restart-shutdown true`. This will disable the dialog.