# How to shutdown oneiric ocelot in two clicks?

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to shut down in two clicks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14794/how-to-shut-down-in-two-clicks)

```
Are you sure you want to close all programs and shut down the computer?
```

When I click shut down I want to shut down! :) This message bugs me. How to avoid this message?

How to do that in oneiric???

Answer (score 1):

If you press your power button, you avoid the message and get this one:

> Shut down this system now?

And you can shut down your computer with one click.