# Missing shutdown icon in Ubuntu 17.04 menu

Tags: unity, shutdown, gui

How can I add a shutdown button to this menu?

In mine it is missing and I am only able to shut down through terminal. My menu only has lock and logout options, and even the logout option doesn't respond when I click it. I want it to appear like this:

[image: shutdown icon in menu]

Comment: @davidbaumann: I don't want to question your experience answering questions, but what made you think Geek Guy is using XFCE/Xubuntu ? From the link I get the impression he has Unity?

Comment: @WillemK: I don't understand where you got the idea that linked question is about Xfce.

Comment: @davidbaumann: I don't think that's what OP is looking for.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: I didn't have an idea. I followed the link Davidbaumann offered and saw references to XFCE.

Comment: @WillemK: One of the answers assumes that the question is about Xfce (with no basis I might add) but it wasn't attracted little votes.

Comment: Am using the latest ubuntu 17.04 as indicated in the title of the edited question, I would be glad to get an answer please.

Comment: @GeekGuy Have you tried any of the solutions on the linked question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I had added to all my launchers is a shutdown icon:

[image]

When clicked it will call the following dialog:

[image]

Save a file named `shutdown.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applicatons` with this content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Application;System;
Comment=To shutdown the computer
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=gnome-session-quit --power-off
Icon=system-shutdown
Name=Shutdown-Button
NoDisplay=false
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

---

To do this, copy all the lines above, open the "Text Editor" (search in Dash) Gedit to paste the text in the still empty page. Then choose *File > Save*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files, browse to `.local/share/applications` and save as `shutdown.desktop`:

[image]

Then open the file browser Nautilus to again browse to `~/.local/share/applications/` to then right click on the `shutdown.desktop` file you had just created there.

Click on it with the **right** mouse button to open the context dropdown menu. Select the last entry *Properties*. In the following dialog open the 
*Permissions* tab to tick on *Allow executing file as program*:

[image]

Watch the icon change to the red shutdown icon. You can then drag this icon to the launcher:

[image]

On clicking on this new entry the following shutdown dialog will appear:

[image]

To have it turn off after a countdown see the following question: [How do I call gnome-session-quit with countdown from Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554576/how-do-i-call-gnome-session-quit-with-countdown-from-unity)

Comment: Thank you @Takkat, I am new to ubuntu and would wish to get commands of creating this file and providing the permissions. Please show.

Comment: Hi @Takkat I have done but it is not working even if I click it from the launcher.

Comment: @GeekGuy: see edit... hope it's clearer now.